# Python jupyter notebook update bug

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I've been using Juptyer Notebook for more than a year now with python3 and I recently saw through the Anaconda Navigator that an update to the 5.7.0 version was available. I installed it but the first Notebook that I tried to launch wouldn't work : I run the most simple expressions such as:

```
test = [1,2,3]
print(len(test))
```

It keeps buffering and nothing comes out of this. Additionally, when I try to define a function, the font doesn't become green and bold like always.

Then I tried to go back to the older version, and that didn't work too. Now I'm back with the up-to-date version but still doesn't work.

I'm on a Windows machine and I don't know very much about source code or precise things to look for in this case.

Comment: Hard to say anything because of the lack of information. 
Try remove Jupyter then install it again. If no success, maybe your anaconda package has been broken. Try to reinstall anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please follow the below steps and share the feedback. It seems that new update installed in a different path.

Step 1:- Get an Anaconda command prompt and run `jupyter notebook` in it, It will probably won't work, but you could get a detail error message saying what's failing.

Step 2:- After your anaconda update, if that's left over from the older version of Anaconda. The shortcut properties might tell you what it's trying to call - there may be a wrong path to Anaconda or something wrong, so you can go to anaconda desktop shortcut, then right click on it and check the properties. And also run the %appdata% command in windows 'Run' and check the installed anaconda app data directory.

Stop 3:- If the shortcut was the issue. You can manually change the "Shortcut target" (in windows) to the following

Eg: C:\Users\'yourusername'\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\Scripts\jupyter-notebook.exe